# MS Word Table Format Through VBA/Macros: Issue with Merge Cells specifically

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

Imagine a table of 7 columns and tons of rows. Some of those tons of rows are Merged containing Notes always containing the string "Note" at the beginning of the cell. In the whole first column includes numbering 10,20,30 etc. even the header.

What could I use to remove the numbering from the header and all the merged cells with "Note" in them?

Comment: It's difficult to imagine your problem without some sample data, however easiest way is probably to copy it to Excel, edit there, then copy back.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description here is code that should work.

```
Sub CleanUpTable()
Dim tbl As Word.Table, r As Integer
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
For r = tbl.rows.Count To 1 Step -1
    If tbl.rows(r).HeadingFormat = True Then
        tbl.rows(r).Cells(1).Range.Text = vbNullString
    End If
    If InStr(1, tbl.rows(r).Cells(2).Range.Text, "Note") Then
        tbl.rows(r).Delete
    End If
Next r
```

End Sub